# How to use API to create Apify Webhook for a specific Task or Actor

Tags: apify

I want to create an Apify actor that creates webhooks for other actors or tasks.  So to bind the webhook to the actor or task, will need to pass in the actorId or the taskId.

The SDK does not seem to support providing an Id to assign the [webhook](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/apify#apifyaddwebhookoptions-promise-object) method.

The API does have a method to create a [webhook](https://docs.apify.com/api/v2#/reference/webhooks/webhook-object/get-webhook) but it unclear how to pass the in the actorId or the taskId.

The `condition` object may be the answer but is not defined in the documentation!

```
'condition': {
    'actorTaskId': 'asdLZtadYvn4mBZmm'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the SDK doesn't do this. The goal of SDK isn't to replicate API 1 to 1. For this, we have the [API JS client](https://docs.apify.com/api/apify-client-js/latest#ApifyClient-webhooks-createWebhook) which is 1 to 1 replication of the API.

You got it right with the condition object but you are right that the description is not ideal. You can use that API call or the client one I sent you.

Comment: i think the sdk includes access to most of the API via the apify.client method?

Comment: Yes, `Apify.client` gives you access to the JS API client.